# Removing Gmail/Hotmail from Allowed Email Input

Tags: php, email, email-validation, craftcms

We're currently having an issue in our company with a free trial form. We only want legit companies to be signing up, at the moment there's a lot of gmail accounts and hotmail accounts etc taking advantage of the trial then creating new accounts then getting another free trial basically.

Here is the Email Validation Function in the module controller in PHP, just wondering how I would edit this to not allow gmail accounts etc as I've jumped in to this already setup code base.

```
protected $allowAnonymous = ['index', 'do-something', 'render-form', 'submit-marketplace', 'validate-email', 'verify-code', 'create-company'];

public function actionValidateEmail()
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $emailValid = false;

    $baseUrl = $_SERVER["ourcompany_API_BASE_URL"]."/userByEmail/";
    $apiKey = $_SERVER["ourcompany_API_KEY"];
    $authHeader = $_SERVER["ourcompany_HEADER"];

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    try {
        $response = $client->request('GET', $baseUrl . $email, [
            'headers' => [
                'content-type' => 'application/vnd.ourcompany.message-v1+json',
                'accept' => 'application/vnd.ourcompany.message-v1+json',
                'authorization' => $authHeader,
                'x-api-key' => $apiKey,
            ]
        ]);
        $emailValid = !($response->getStatusCode() == 200);
    } catch (ClientException $e) {
        // ClientException raised for 400 level errors
        $emailValid = true;
    }

    return json_encode(array("valid" => $emailValid));
}
```

Then the front-end looks like this.

```
   <form style="display: none;" method="post" id="create-company-form" action="/">
        <input
          type="hidden"
          name="action"
          value="ourcompany-in-action-module/ourcompany-in-action/create-company"
        />
        <input id="companyName" type="text" name="companyName" value="" />
        <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
        <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" value="" />
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="" />
        <input id="mobile" type="text" name="mobile" value="" />
        <input id="country" type="text" name="country" value="" />
        <input id="timezone" type="text" name="timezone" value="" />
      </form>

      <form style="display: none;" method="post" id="validate-email-form" action="/">
        <input
          type="hidden"
          name="action"
          value="company-in-action-module/company-in-action/validate-email"
        />
        <input id="emailValidationField" type="email" name="email" value="" />
      </form>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp` with script to see if is gmail then create error in the input.
**Js solution:**

```js
function Clear() {
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML ='';
}
function CheckMail() {
    return RegExp(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\@gmail([\.])com/g);
}
function Validation(elem) {
isGmail=CheckMail();
var result = true;
if(isGmail.test(elem)) {
        result=false;
        $('#error').html('Gmail is not allowed!');
    }else{
     $('#error').html(' Domain Allowed!');
    }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="email" onChange="Validation(this.value)" onClick="Clear()">

<p id="error"></p>
```

**PHP solution:**

```
function Test($value) {
    $notallowed=array(
      'gmail.com', 'gmail.it'
    );
     // Split the email address at the @ symbol
    $email_parts = explode( '@', $value );

    // Pop off everything after the @ symbol
    $domain = array_pop( $email_parts );
    if ( in_array( $domain, $notallowed ) ) {
      return false;
    }

      return true; 


}
if(Test('test@lol.com')==FALSE){
 echo 'Not allowed';   
}else{

 echo 'Allowed';   
}
```

You  will adapt that to your situation.